# php loop pop up box and dialog from jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, dialog, popup

Hi I am using a framework called CodeIgniter and its a sample of MVC. I need a popup box where it will display the subvalues of an application however my dialog box is not working everytime I echo it. but you see i need to loop the dialog box for different values. my code is below

```
<?php 

        foreach($people as $row){
          echo"<div id='dialog' title='Basic dialog'>".$row->app_name."</div>";
          echo "<button id='opener'>".$row->app_name."</button>";}
                                ?>
```

My javascrip code is fro jquery

```
  <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
          },
          hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
          }
        });

        $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
          $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
      });
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation

```
$(document).on("click" ,  "#opener" ,function() {
          $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
 });
```

Comment: Because id is unique but in your case it is not unique that why it is not working man

Answer (score 0):

Update the code as below:

```
<?php 
    $i = 1;
    foreach($people as $row){
      echo"<div id='dialog". $i."' title='Basic dialog'>".$row->app_name."</div>";
      echo "<button id='opener". $i."'>".$row->app_name."</button>";
    ?>
    <script>
        $(function() {
          $( "#dialog<?php echo $i?>" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
              effect: "blind",
              duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
              effect: "explode",
              duration: 1000
            }
          });

          $( "#opener<?php echo $i?>" ).click(function() {
            $( "#dialog<?php echo $i?>" ).dialog( "open" );
          });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
     $i++;
    }
?>
```

Basically there will be multiple popup and you need to give unique id to each popup and button.

Comment: it is not a dialog box. it is just listing the files with in the dialog box. i need a popup

Answer (score 0):

to use **id** in this situation is not good idea ... you should change id to **class**

```
 echo "<button class='opener'>".$row->app_name."</button>";
```

then

```
$( ".opener" ).click(function() {
     $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

id is unique you should use a class

---

**Enjoy :)**